# issue on requests.get (using python 3.8), even setting verify=False

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import os, sys

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) \
     AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
     Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/605.1.15"
}

BRCO11_02 = 'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=195321&cvm=true'

cont = requests.get(BRCO11_02, headers=headers, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(cont.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

Comment: _"I'm having an Error"_: What is the error? Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Hi. Thx. It's an issue, not an error. The content returned by BS4 looks like a crypto header. Here it is: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)
C:\Users\barbera\.conda\envs\port\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
"PGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgo8TUVUQSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiIGNvbnRlbnQ9InRleHQvaHRtbDsgY2hhcnNldD1VVEYtOCI+Cjx0aXRsZT5B...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a `Accept: text/html` header, instructs the webserver to return a HTML document:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Accept": "text/html"
}

BRCO11_02 = 'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=195321&cvm=true'

cont = requests.get(BRCO11_02, headers=headers, verify=False)

print(cont.content)
```

Out:

```
<html>\n<head>\n<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<title>ANEXO 39-I : Informe Mensal</title>...
```

Comment: It works. Thx a lot,  Maurice.